# Where can I find an updated tutorial for Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I need to write a small application in python. From what I read, `Tkinter` should be a reasonable option to use. I tried several tutorials about it and all said I should import the module using

```
import Tkinter
```

which fails. using

```
import tkinter
```

however, succeed. From that I gather there was a version update since the tutorial(s) was written. I tried to ignore this, but quickly I come upon errors which are not solved as easily. I guess I need to either switch tutorial or a gui library. So do you have a link to a recent tutorial or to a freshly documented gui library for python?

Answer (score 1):

The only significant changes to tkinter from python 2.x to python 3.x is how it is imported. The core functionality is the same. Any tutorial for tkinter 2.x should work just fine for 3.x once you get past the import issue.

That being said, the tutorial at tkdocs.com is probably the most modern tutorial at the time I write this. See http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html